# Why my If condition is returning wrong result?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm a student currently studying VBA in one of my classes, where the current assignment is to pull data from a .txt file and display it, as well as total it, and then grade the total. using arrays I've been successful in the first two parts using arrays, but when trying to factor in the total for a grade the array only takes the starting numbers into account. Any thoughts? Code below

```
Sub Categories()

Dim Locale As String, State(1 To 50) As Variant
Dim Serial(1 To 50) As Single, i As Single
Dim path As String, j As Single
Dim Score(1 To 50, 1 To 7) As Single
Dim IndexGrade(1 To 50) As Single
Dim Total(1 To 50) As Single
Locale = ActiveWorkbook.path

path = Locale & "US_States.txt"

Open path For Input As #1

For i = 1 To 50 Step 1
    Input #1, Serial(i), State(i)
    Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Serial(i)
    Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 2).Value = State(i)
         For j = 1 To 7 Step 1
            Input #1, Score(i, j)
            Total(i) = Total(i) + Score(i, j)
            Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 3).Value = Total(i)
        Next j
   Total(i) = Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 3).Value
   If 0 <= Total(i) < 100 Then
    Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 4).Value = "A"
    ElseIf 100 <= Total(i) < 200 Then
    Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 4).Value = "B"
    ElseIf 200 <= Total(i) < 300 Then
    Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 4).Value = "C"
    ElseIf 300 <= Total(i) Then
    Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 4).Value = "D"
    End If
Next i

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you over-writing your total(i)? Also that `IF` condition is wrong. This VBA not python.

Comment: I love that you're using the `Sheet1` code name, and explicitly specify the `.Value` member call. However your indentation could use some help, and variables should be declared closer to their usage. Programming-wise (language-agnostic), the procedure should have a meaningful name, and *do one thing* - this should definitely be broken down into smaller, more specialized procedures and functions, be it only to separate input from processing and output. See my user profile for some useful links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your `If` condition. In VBA `1 < 2 < 1` evaluates to `true`. That's why even if your `total(i)` is more than 100, it always evaluates to true and your `elseif` is not coming into play.

In VBA/VB6, type conversion is simply evil.

---

You nee to rewrite your `If` and `elseif` conditions

Example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim x   As Long
    Dim y   As Long

    x = 101
    y = 99

    '/ What you are doing
    If 0 <= x < 1 Then
        MsgBox "This is not python."
    End If

    '/ How you should do it.
    If y >= 0 And y < 100 Then
        MsgBox "This is how you do it in VBA."
    End If

End Sub
```